# Signing active x control And marking as safe

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, activex, digital-signature

I have developed an active x control and signed it with certificate. I know that digital signing is needed , so that the browser knows that the active x comes valid source. 
My asp.net form has a button , which invokes a method on activex control as -

```
function test() 
    {
        objActiveX = document.getElementById("activeXUploadAttachment");                
         var base64Image = objActiveX.ParseClipbpoardDataAsBase64()
```

But it errors on browser stating that the - IE has blocked this site from using an active x control in an unsafe manner. ( Please see attachment).

So should I have to develop the active x control which implement IObjectSafety and also signed digitally, so that it can execute on client browser without any warnings from IE. Any examples.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

a good example from "[A Complete ActiveX Web Control Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/CompleteActiveX.aspx)" may help you!